# MySQL Insert into different tables based on a column from a select statement

Tags: mysql

Hopefully this one isn't too bad I just haven't been able to figure it out.

So I have a table with data by date. I need to aggregate the data in that table off of a field, lets say profit and customer, and then insert that into a table that is named for the month the transaction took place.

For example lets say I have the follow data:

1. 20170101, Michael, 100$
2. 20170301 George, 200$
3. 20170104, Carla, 50$
4. 20170115, Michael, 500$

I would need to insert into a table called January the aggregate for all the transactions that happened in january by customer. That would look like this:

January

1. Michael, 600$
2. Carly, 50$

March

1. George, 200$

Hopefully I explained that well enough for it to make sense.

Thank you in advance for all the help!

edit1:

I think I explained it badly. The group by and aggregate of the data is not my problem. It is the inserting it into another table based on the month. I do not know which table it will go into until i hit the record. So basically I need to dynamically insert into a table based on a column in a select statement, the date in this case

Comment: An insert statement can only insert into a single table. Are you trying to get a solution for this in a single query, or can you put this into a stored proc where you can use loops or dynamic SQL?

Comment: I think a stored proc will be the best way. I just didn't know you couldn't do a dynamic insert into multiple tables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need aggregation in this case. You just need to fetch the data for each month and insert into the appropriate month table. This looks much like a task that can be done using a stored procedure. Since you want to insert the data into a table (the table of the month) you have to see that the data in this table does not get polluted by multiple insertions. To prevent that it will be better to go by a trigger on your tables on insert or update.

See [MySQL Triggers](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just aggregate them in a group by at the end? If you have the data already in one table, why duplicate it? Do something like:

```
GROUP BY SUBSTR(date_column, 4, 2)
```

or

```
WHERE SUBSTR(date_column, 4,2)=01
```

Comment: This is not the solution, aggregation is not necessary.

Comment: Based on the way it was initially worded, grouping data or sorting them with a WHERE is actually best. Duplicating data in a SQL database goes against 3NF